# WEBSOCKETS Provider url for binance smart chain

Tags: contract-invocation, events, bsc, web3-providers, websocket

I have a contract deployed in Binance smart chain. I have written a script that will help me read the events logs from the Blockchain. currently, I tested that with the local hardhat network itself, where the provider is

```
const provider = new ethers.providers.WebSocketProvider(
`http://127.0.0.1:8545/`
```

);
and it's working fine.

I also research and found out the provider for ethereum mainnet is

```
wss://eth-mainnet.alchemyapi.io/v2/private_key
```

What is the url to connect to the binance smart chain?

Answer (score 1):

[Chainstack](https://chainstack.com/build-better-with-bnb-smart-chain/) offers [WebSocket endpoints](https://docs.chainstack.com/docs/manage-your-node#view-node-access-and-credentials) for BSC